# COMMIT inside Unit Transaction Tibco Business works

Tags: jdbc, transactions, commit, tibco, businessworks

This is tibco business works code. I've two stored procedures inside a JDBC transaction group. These stored procedures are invoked one after another and have their own COMMIT statement. Incase, the 2nd stored proc fails for some reason, will the first stored proc's actions rolled back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they won't be rolled back since they have been committed during the execution of the first SP.